# How display data in one row from multiple columns in mysql table

Tags: mysql

i have a table about product review. I saved data in table like this

```
 id| value|
___|______|
1  |Our pr|
2  |oduct |
3  |availa|
4  |ble in|
5  |all re|
6  |tailer|
7  |shop. |
```

I want dispaly in one row or paragraph 
like this Our product available in all retailer shop.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` as you want to combine data in separate rows.

Try this

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(value SEPARATOR '') FROM yourtablename`

Comment: @user1464025 : If you think Junaid answered your question please mark it accepted. This is how SO works. ***See [here, how to accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)***

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mysql> set @a:=''

mysql> select @a:= concat (@a, ' ', value) from table1.
```

with that you'll have all the value in @a, and to display

```
mysql> select @a;
```

Comment: Wrong. With that you will just have one row at a time in @a

Comment: @tombom why you say that? can you tested and let me know your result?

Comment: How about you try it? CONCAT operates on rows, GROUP_CONCAT concatenates the strings in one group. Try your query with the test data from the question and you will get nothing but `shop.` Please edit your answer or delete it or prove me wrong.

Comment: And most important, make sure it's right before you post when you're not sure.

Comment: @tombom http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1262, I did another way to display the same result, those are options... please before to say 'edit or delete post' search a little bit about the different solution that a problem can have, if that example is not enough let me know and I'll send you "SQL variables for Dummies"

Comment: Okay, okay, you proved me wrong, sorry. But please don't be so whiny. See it positive, I could have downvoted you ;)